# Data Extraction from SAP to Azure Datalake with Datafactory using SAP CDC

Tags: azure-data-factory, hana, data-extraction, cds, function-module

I am extracting ABAP CDS views from the SAP with Data Factory using SAP CDC.  The ABAP CDS views are delta enabled but anytime I try to extract full load, I get the following error:

> Message=Sap Odp operation 'Execute function module RODPS_REPL_ODP_PREFETCH with pointer 20220810084136.000021000' failed. Error Number: '666', error message: 'An exception with the type CX_SY_DYNAMIC_OSQL_SEMANTICS occurred, but was neither handled locally, nor declared in a RAISING clause',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper

And when I try delta extraction, I get this error:

> Message=Sap Odp operation 'OpenOdpRead' failed. Error Number: '500', error message: 'Source ZB4H_AUPH_2  Does not support deltas',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper,'

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to implement [sap note 3070258](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/3070258)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).